# How Can Declare Node Specific Constants on Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

How can I define a node specific constant BASE_DIRECTORY, that I can use within my scripts.

For example:

- on node1, BASE_DIRECTORY="/data/apps/folder1"
- on node2, BASE_DIRECTORY="/var/folder20"

And within my scripts, I want to resolve $BASE_DIRECTORY to do actions on that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define any custom attribute in your model source like `base-directory=/some/value`, e.g:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="db" hostname="192.168.56.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" base-directory="/home/vagrant/myapp1" />
  <node name="node01" description="Node 01" tags="db" hostname="192.168.56.21" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" base-directory="/home/vagrant/myapp2" />
  <node name="node02" description="Node 02" tags="bk" hostname="192.168.56.22" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" base-directory="/home/vagrant/myapp3" />
</project>
```

Now call the `${node.base-directory}` env var (`@node.base-directory@` on inline-scripts or `$RD_NODE_BASE-DIRECTORY` for "external scripts").

Tested using this job definition:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: c16356aa-b4c1-465e-9ac0-0bd89aa8bc30
  loglevel: INFO
  name: TestRemoteJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: .*
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - script: echo @node.base-directory@
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: c16356aa-b4c1-465e-9ac0-0bd89aa8bc30
```

Check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IoIP.jpg).

To use `RD_*` vars on remote SSH nodes, please take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command).

Comment: Appreciate your perfectly well detailed answer, thank you!